# Dagger Hilt abstract class with types

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

Hello everyone I am trying to use Dagger-Hilt and I am wondering how is it possible to achieve this code bellow?

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
abstract class BaseActivity <B : ViewDataBinding, VM : ViewModel> : IActivity<VM>, AppCompatActivity() {

   @Inject
   lateinit var someClass: SomeClass
}
```

Gradle returns this error:

```
 BaseActivity_GeneratedInjector.java:10: error: <identifier> expected
    topLevelClass = BaseActivity<B, VM>.class
                                        ^error: [Hilt]
  class java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is the generated Java class:

```
@OriginatingElement(
    topLevelClass = BaseActivity<B, VM>.class
)
@GeneratedEntryPoint
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent.class)
@Generated("dagger.hilt.android.processor.internal.androidentrypoint.InjectorEntryPointGenerator")
public interface BaseActivity_GeneratedInjector {
  void injectBaseActivity(BaseActivity baseActivity);
}
```

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand this is bug inside Hilt.

Check related github issue: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2042

You can fix this by moving `@AndroidEntryPoint` from abstract class with parameters into child class without type parameters.