# <identifier> expected android Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I would like to try Hilt DI in my app

I done all the steps to add Hilt to my App but   my problem is hilt show me error in My BaseFragment
says :

**error:  expected
topLevelClass = BaseFragment<T, D>.class  ^error: [Hilt]**

and BaseFragment is simple  :

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
abstract class BaseFragment<T : ViewModel,D : ViewDataBinding>() : Fragment() {

@Inject
lateinit var viewModel: T by viewModels()


 }
```

and for viewModel ***by viewModels()***  not working show me error of

> Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead. Type
> 'Lazy' has no method 'setValue(BaseFragment<T, D>, KProperty<*>,
> T)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate for var (read-write
> property).**

so i used Factory like i used in  Dagger and it works but still my problem in

BaseFragment

I appreciate you to help me out and thanks in advance

**EDIT :**
oppen this [issues](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2042) on github and they says it was a bug and they will ban @AndroidEntryPoint for base classes with type parameters –

Answer (score 5):

As I already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63413747/7569679://) this might be a bug inside Hilt.

Check related github issue: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2042

You can fix this by moving `@AndroidEntryPoint` from abstract class with parameters into child class without type parameters.

Comment: yes it is a bug i oppen this [issues](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2042) on github and they says it was a bug  and they will ban @AndroidEntryPoint for base classes with type parameters